# Flask Redirect From Jinja HTML Template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I can call the redirect method from .py file like this

```
@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def logout_page():
    logout_user()
    flash('Anda telah logout', category='success')
    return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
```

How to call that redirect method from the Jinja HTML template?

I've tried something like this

```
{% if not current_user.is_authenticated %} 
  {% redirect(url_for('login_page')) %}
{% else
...
%}
```

But it's not works

Comment: A redirect is based on the `Location` HTTP header in combination with a status code and is an alternative response from the server, which signals the client to make a new request. Use within a template cannot work. Why not use the [`login_required`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_required) decorator to tell the endpoint to redirect when the user is not logged in?

Comment: how to use login_required to tell the endpoint to redirect?

I tried a sample on the documentation

@app.route('/post')
@login_required
def post():
    pass

it's only showing an unauthorized message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [`login_required`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_required) decorator, it will ensure that the user is logged in before calling the endpoint. Thus, the template is not rendered at all. The user can be directed to login.

```py
from flask_login import login_required

# ...

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def secret_endpoint():
    return 'This is secret.'
```

In order to implement such a forwarding to the login, the attribute  [`login_view`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.LoginManager.login_view) must be set for the `LoginManager`. Here it is determined where the user is directed if he is not logged in.
If this attribute is not set, only the HTTP error 401 is returned.

```py
from flask_login import LoginManager

# ...

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'login_page'
login_manager.init_app(app)

# ...
```

You can find an explanation of the behavior in the documentation [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#customizing-the-login-process).